# Symfony3 routing bundle prefix locale

Tags: locale, symfony, prefix

I am working on Symfony3 project where I want to introduce language. And for that I added prefix to the the bundle routing config.

```
project_front:
    resource: "@ProjectFrontBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /{locale}
    requirements: {"locale": "en|fr" }
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectFrontBundle:Default:index, locale: da}
```

When I hit:

```
http://domain.com/en/login
http://domain.com/da/login
```

in both cases translation works fine, but as I click on any link. the prefix in url fallback to the default locale that is da

I am in doubt, that if I am missing any other config.

Comment: Have you read this http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html ?

Comment: @DonCallisto Thanks, actually I noticed that I was using locale in the configuration and in my Listner, whereas I should have use _locale. That made it work.